# Difference between ARM and GCCE build?

Tags: symbian, arm

What is the difference between ARM and GCCE? I am learning development on Symbian platform. I created a tested simple GUI application. Compiled and run on simulator. But don't know whether to compile in GCCE or ARM in order to run on my phone E61i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbian OS runs on ARM processors. To build code for a phone you need to use a compiler based on the Application Binary Interface for ARM environments.
And you have two options here — GNU Compiler Collection for Embedded (GCCE) and ARM's RealView Compiler Tools (RVCT). GCCE comes with your SDK and it's free. RVCT is a commercial compiler, it creates binaries that have more effective performance compared to GCCE builds. Symbian OS is build with the help of the RVCT.
For most applications GCCE is all you need. Unless a high performance is a must for your application, go for GCCE.
For further reading check [this](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/BuildTools/native/index.html).

Comment: Not entirely true - RVCT4.0 is free for use by individuals and companies of less than 20 employees. See http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Installing_ARM_RVCT_4.0